# Scala Selenium webdriver Unable to click an element found using XPath

Tags: scala, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I wrote this simple snippet to click on a menu item, this menu item does not have a class or id, so I have to find the element using an attribute but I get this error that the element is not clickable.

**Scala Code**

```
val s =  find(xpath("//tr[@aria-label='Show By ']")).get.underlying
click on s
```

**Error**

```
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (bf45b57213899780871d25030c5838d7)] -> xpath: //tr[@aria-label='Show By ']]
←[31m  The code passed to eventually never returned normally. Attempted 16 times over 20.156217392000002 seconds. Last failure message: unknown error:
 Element is not clickable at point (844, 903). Other element would receive the click: <td class="dijitReset dijitMenuArrowCell" role="presentation">..
.</td>←[0m
```

**HTML Code**

```
<tr class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" id="dijit_PopupMenuItem_1" aria-label="Show By " widgetid="dijit_PopupMenuItem_1" aria-haspopup="true" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">
<td class="dijitReset dijitMenuItemIconCell" role="presentation">
    <span role="presentation" class="dijitInline dijitIcon dijitMenuItemIcon" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode"></span>
</td>
<td class="dijitReset dijitMenuItemLabel" colspan="2" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode,textDirNode" id="dijit_PopupMenuItem_1_text">Show By</td>
<td class="dijitReset dijitMenuItemAccelKey" style="display: none" data-dojo-attach-point="accelKeyNode" id="dijit_PopupMenuItem_1_accel"></td>
<td class="dijitReset dijitMenuArrowCell" role="presentation">
    <span data-dojo-attach-point="arrowWrapper">
        <span class="dijitInline dijitIcon dijitMenuExpand"></span>
        <span class="dijitMenuExpandA11y">+</span>
    </span>
</td>
```

Comment: tr tag contains id, you can use that id. And I that element clickable? Can you post your URL??

Comment: @SarithaG..problem is these id's keep changing during the project, these are auto generated by dojo

Comment: Ok..Then you can take xpath from the root node.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the element you are trying to click is being covered by another (probably invisible) element.

There are different ways to handle this, but the simplest is to just click the element using javascript.

```
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

is how it is done in java.  I have no idea what the correct syntax is in scala.